# Product Import with Image Links on another website

Tags: product, import

I have a Product list with over 16,000 items in it. I followed the System>import> and successfully uploaded all 16000 items. For the images however, I have link to my distributors website for example, image_small> http://cdn.distributorsname.com/images/1x1/small/a/a/image1.jpg

Now, the images are not showing for any of the products. If it was just 1 or two products I could have uploaded the images manually, for 16,000 its difficult. So, please help me the soonest you can. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think the native importer fetches images via http. You need to place them locally where the Magento admin server is.

Comment: Which Magento version are you in?